# Invariant determinant for a specific class of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$     be a such real $2\times{2}$ matrix  that the sum of elements on diagonal and anti-diagonal are equal i.e. $a+d=b+c$.

$\\$

**Question:**

- How to prove (if it is always true) that for this kind of matrices:
  $\det(A) = \det(A+k\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix})$
  for any real $k$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that determinant of $A = ad-bc...(1)$.

Now the matrix $A +k\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1\\
  1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. It can be simplified to $\begin{bmatrix} a+k & b+k\\
c+k & d+k \end{bmatrix}$. It's determinant is $((a+k)(d+k)-(b+k)(c+k)) = ad-bc +k((a+d)-(b+c))...(2)$.

---

If $(1)=(2)$, we will have $$a+d=b+c$$ which is true. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes thank you. If know now that this determinant is invariant I can easily calculate it i.e. $det(A)= -(b-a)(c-a)$

Comment: ... and it is easy way to generate matrices with very big entries but with small non-zero determinants.. for example $det \begin{bmatrix} 705781 & 705787  \\ 
705821 & 705827 
 \end{bmatrix}= -240$

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply expand 
$$
\det\left(A+k\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
and see what you get.

You will get something like
$$
\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a+k & b+k \\
c+k & d+k \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)
=
ad - bc + k (\dots).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use linearity of the determinant obtaining

\begin{eqnarray}
\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}a +k & b+k\\ c +k & d+k\end{array}\right]&=&\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}a  & b\\ c  & d\end{array}\right]+k\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}a  & b\\ 1  & 1\end{array}\right]+k\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}1  & 1\\ c  & d\end{array}\right]+k^2\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}1  & 1\\ 1  & 1\end{array}\right]\\
&=& \det\left[\begin{array}{cc}a  & b\\ c  & d\end{array}\right]+k(a-b+d-c)\\
&=& \det\left[\begin{array}{cc}a  & b\\ c  & d\end{array}\right].
\end{eqnarray}
This can be probably generalized in dimensions larger than 2.

Comment: The excellent answer... generalization would be very interesting...

Comment: If you would construct a generalization for  higher dimensions it could be one of  the answers for the http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056935/matrices-with-invariant-determinant ..