# Matrices with invariant determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $v$ be a vector and $A$ be a real matrix generated with some algorithm from components of the vector i.e. $A=f(v)$.

Now I'm interested in such matrices $A$ that for them

$\det(A)=\det(f(v))= \det(f(v+k\mathbf{1}))$  for any real $k$,

where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector consisted of only $1$ so the $v+k\mathbf{1}$  is the vector $v$ translated by the vector $k\mathbf{1}$.

> **Question:**
>     what are examples of matrices with such property ?

I've collected some:

- the first matrix would be the matrix $2\times{2}$  constructed from a  $4\times{1}$ vector with
  some specific properties from [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055210/invariant-determinant-for-a-specific-class-of-matrices),
- the second matrix would be $n\times{n}$  [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) constructed from a general form of $n\times{1}$ vector,
- the third matrix would be $n\times{n}$ matrix from    [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034108/a-non-vandermonde-matrix-with-vandermonde-like-determinant) constructed from a vector as above.

> What other non-trivial examples of such matrices can be presented?